# Android Modify Parent View after Child is Drawn

Tags: android, user-interface, view, ondraw, uiview-hierarchy

I am having issues with modifying a parent view after a child is drawn. I need data from the child after the onDraw method is called. I need to use this information to modify the parent view. So after the child is drawn, how would I go about modifying the parent view (drawing on its canvas)? I'm sorry that I don't have code, but I don't know how to implement what I'm asking (thus the question). Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do it in the child's onDraw() method?

Comment: Well I need to set links to the children (draw lines) and they could be linked together so its possible that the child doesn't know that it has a link to another sibling. So what I want to do is just grab the coordinates from the children and draw the lines in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

I took your advice Vee and I ended up doing everything in the child. Its not pretty, I basically grab the parent and traverse through the children getting the parameters that I need... So, that is the solution that I used. Just when you are rendering the child you can reference the parent and then pull all the information you need.